# Issue in Connecting to SQL Server 2008 R2 from .Net application on a different Server

Tags: c#, ssl, ado.net, .net-4.5, tls1.2

I am trying to fetch data from SQL Server 2008 R2 residing on a server(I do not have access to this server to make any changes). The application I developed to fetch data is a simple .net 4.5 console application hosted on a server where I have a full control of. Below is the error I am getting:

***A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.)***

Any suggestion to establish the connection from the application server side?

I have tried all the below,but no luck:

1. Tried all the below attributes:

   - Encrypt
   - TrustServerCertificate
   - Trusted_Connection
2. Tried below on the application side:

   `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true; ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;`
3. Tried using below on the web.config

   `<AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSystemDefaultTlsVersions=false"/>`

Comment: Totally unrelated but you may want to consider an upgrade: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2 2008 R2 is way out of support.

Comment: Are you deliberately working with ancient technology? I don't think it will solve your problem but _I_ would at least try to stay up-to-date with the parts I _do_ control. Having both more up-to-date, you'll also have safer modes of communication at your disposal.

Comment: But on your question: The operator of that Database, can they provide you a definitvely working connection string / set of configs? If anybody, they should know or at least be able to figure it out.

Comment: "they do not possess a common algorithm" means the two sides don't share any enabled ciphers in common. Make sure both Windows are fully up to date with the latest updates. SQL 2008R2, while completely out of date now, does have a TLS1.2 update, see https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/2008/05/sql-server-2008-r2-versions.html. Use the free IIS Crypto tool on both machines to check that TLS1.2 and modern secure ciphers are both enabled.

Comment: Thanks everyone.. Issue was resolved by enabling the TLS1.0

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved by enabling the TLS1.0 on the server where I had control of.